# Run 2 os's (raspbian and kodi)

Tags: raspbian, kodi, openelec

Can I run 2 os's together?
I want to run my tor relay, but I have to reboot to jump over to Openelec, which causes downtime on the relay.

It seems launching kodi form the command line, then returning to command line would be ideal- although I know Openelec is meant to be its own os.

Is there a work around?

Comment: You could run tor services in the background parallel with openelec. This might be slow. Alternatively, you could get two RPIs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Kodi is not an OS, it is an application. OpenELEC on the other hand is the combination of Kodi and an OS, bundled in such a way that Kodi is the only interface you work with.

So, you could just simply install Raspbian, pull Kodi using apt-get, and tweak the kodi install as per the wiki on [kodi.tv](http://kodi.tv)

Comment: Oh, thank you for the clarification. That makes more sense, I will figure it out- but would kodi operate the same way?

Comment: Yes, minus all the special tuning the folks at OpenELEC have done to make its experience rock-solid